# How to catch sql error in Django Rest Framework serializer?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django Rest Framework endpoint to which an external party sends data in a fairly high volume. Because it was running about 200 inserts per second I checked the queries it was making. I found that it actually first did a SELECT query to check whether there was a duplicate id. Since I didn't think there would be any (or at least not many) duplicate keys I wanted to disable that check. So I added this line to my Serializer:

```
id = serializers.UUIDField(validators=[])  # Disable the validators for the id, which improves performance (rps) by over 200%
```

And as you can see in the comment, it greatly enhances the performance. However, one disadvantage of it is that it gives a 500 error if a duplicate key is in fact posted, saying

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

How would I be able to catch this Database error and returning a neat response instead of throwing this 500 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to override the serializer's `create` method to catch the error.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    [ ... ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            return super().create(validated_data)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(str(e))
```

You have to override the serializer's `update` as well if you allow `PUT` on the object.

There might be better to place the hook, depending on your use case. It have to be somewhere on the serializer and the try-catch has to be around where the objects `save()` method is called. For you, it might work to override the serializer's `save()` method with roughly the same code as above.